# Make Cytoscape.js Node a Link

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape.js to make a simple graph network.  I'd like each node to contain an href to link to more information, or on hover to display information as well.  Is it possible to add this functionality to cytoscape nodes?

Comment: Have you reviewed [the demos](http://js.cytoscape.org/#demos), the [linkout demo](http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/eb861f83fb741628342f/) for example?

Answer (score 7):

First, add href to data tag. like this:

```
{ data: { id: 'c' , href: 'example.com'} }
```

Then insert this in script:

```
cy.on('tap', 'node', function(){
  try { // your browser may block popups
    window.open( this.data('href') );
  } catch(e){ // fall back on url change
    window.location.href = this.data('href');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add information when generating the node like:

```
data: {id: 'nodeName', label: 'nodeLabel', link: 'your_href'}
```

Then you could use [qtip](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip) to display said link or merely make it part of the label.

You can call the link for each node using `data(link)` for the labels or `this.data("link")` in qtip:

```
{selector: 'edge', style: {'label': 'data(link)',}}
```

Answer (score 0):

basically like this:

```
{"selector": "node", "style": {'href link': "https://images.google.com/puppies","width": 50, "height": 5}}
```